# OpenSSL RSA benchmark vs. actual RSA_sign() speed

Tags: performance, cryptography, rsa

I'm currently developing a system involving RSA and noticed that RSA signing/decrypting is quite slow. However, there is something I can't quite wrap my head around:

When measuring RSA-2048 speed on a specific system with the OpenSSL "speed" command, I get the following:

```
                  sign    verify    sign/s verify/s
rsa 2048 bits  0.003656s 0.000105s    273.5   9514.4
```

When measuring the speed in my own application (using gettimeofday() and signing with OpenSSL's RSA_sign() 100 times), I get 44ms (compared to 3.7ms above) however.

I don't see how that makes sense. That's over 10 times longer than OpenSSL's own benchmark tool takes. What magical function do they use to achieve this speed?

I also tried the LibTomCrypt library and the best I get there (combined with TomsFastMath) is 10ms. Still a lot compared to 3.7ms. And the same is the case for other systems I tested on as well.

Any ideas why there is such a huge discrepancy here?

Comment: In RSA_sign() you specify a hash (in this case a 20-byte SHA-1 hash) that is then signed. That's what signing is anyway (you only sign the hash, not the data). I would think they do the same in their tool? Doubling the size doesn't affect performance in any way.

Comment: Ah ok. Doc size completely irrelevant then sorry. Did you look at the OpenSSL benchmark code to see exactly what they're doing?

Comment: They are calling RSA_sign() as well and even using gettimeofday() if I use the "-elapsed" option.

Comment: @user1941044 No, not really. Normally the hashing is thought to be part of the signature generation method, and it is specified as such in PKCS#1. The hash is padded and then modular exponentiation is performed to create the final signature (+integer to octet string conversion, to be complete). Hashing small amounts of data takes much less time than the modular exponentiation however, so for *small sets* of data the size of the data hardly matters.

Comment: The most important factor in RSA signature generation over relatively small amounts of data is the key size. Do you use a similar size of the key? Does your key contain all the components required to apply the Chinese Remainder Theorem (CRT)? Do you use file IO or other OS operations? Multi-threading?

Comment: As I stated above, they use the exact same function(s) that I'm using (hence they use the same padding, etc.). A new key (2048 bits) is generated every time and the time is measured over a for loop containing nothing but RSA_sign(). That's exactly what they do (I checked their source). It's definitely not a bug on my side. I just don't understand how their tool arrives at these extremely low runtimes.

Comment: Title should be changed to reflect that the user built his OpenSSL library with compiler optimizations disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, turns out I compiled the OpenSSL library without running "./config" first, so it was built without any platform-specific optimizations (amazing what a difference something like this can make). When using the benchmark tool from that build I got the same slow performance as in my own application.